# Overridden evaluate methods in custom hive UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, hive-udf

I am new to write custom udf for hive. I have tried writing custom udf for toupper function succecfully.

```html
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

@Description(
    name="SimpleUDFExample",
    value="returns 'hello x', where x is whatever you give it (STRING)",
    extended="SELECT simpleudfexample('world') from foo limit 1;"
    )
class SimpleUDFExample extends UDF {
  
 public Text evaluate(Text input) {
     if(input == null) return null;
     return new Text("Hello " + input.toString());
   }
}
```

I have to write different implementations of evaluate based on different input parameters.

My query is - How can i write multiple evaluate methods in a single class.Do I need to write different classes for different methods? If i write these overridden methods in a single class then How Hive is going to differ between different method which contains same type parameter.

Please Guide me about the right way.

Answer (score 1):

In hive you can overload the method same as JAVA. But in UDF you have to use Hadoop Datatypes likes IntWritable, FloatWritable...

Please find below the code.

```
public class ToUpper extends UDF{

    public String evaluate(Text word) {
        String upperCase=word.toString();
        return upperCase;

    }

    public String evaluate(IntWritable word) {
        String upperCase="Error : Input type is Integer. Cannot convert to UpperCase";
        return upperCase;

    }

    public String evaluate(FloatWritable word) {
        String upperCase="Error : Input type is Float. Cannot convert to UpperCase";
        return upperCase;

    }

    public String evaluate(LongWritable word) {
        String upperCase="Error : Input type is Long. Cannot convert to UpperCase";
        return upperCase;

    }



}
```

For more Information about UDF visit [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Answer (score 0):

Is overloading of this type possible?

Like -

```
public class ExampleUDF extends UDF{

    public Integer evaluate(Integer num) {
        return num*2;

    }

    public Integer evaluate(Integer num1, Integer num2) {
        return num1*num2;
    }
}
```